# how can i fix my sql developer if it dont show my procedures code?

Tags: oracle, function, stored-procedures, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

today my sql developer and my team sql developer when we try to see a procedure or a function  it doesn't show the code.

when we click a stored procedure in the sql developer tree, it only show:

```
create or replace
```

[image: problem]

we tried restarting sql developer.

we tried reinstall the sql developer.

we tried deleting and creating the connection again.

all of them did't work.

Comment: Open the log panel (from view menu), see the Statements section. You'll see the query we run to populate your code. Try running that in a SQL worksheet, what comes back?

Comment: i saw this:


SELECT LINE,POSITION,TEXT,ATTRIBUTE FROM USER_ERRORS WHERE TYPE=? AND NAME=? 

result: Falta el parámetro IN o OUT en el índice:: 1

i saw this too: 

WITH src AS (SELECT ROWNUM,LINE,TEXT,origin_con_id FROM SYS.ALL_SOURCE 
 WHERE TYPE = :TYPE AND OWNER = :OWNER AND NAME = :NAME)
 SELECT text FROM src, (SELECT max(origin_con_id) max_orig FROM src)  
 WHERE origin_con_id = max_orig 
 ORDER BY LINE

Comment: The second one gets your code, the first one gets any errors

Comment: ok ok, 
this is the result


ORA-01114: error de E/S al escribir el bloque en el archivo  (bloque número )
01114. 00000 -  "IO error writing block to file %s (block # %s)"
*Cause:    The device on which the file resides is probably offline. If the
           file is a temporary file, then it is also possible that the device
           has run out of space. This could happen because disk space of
           temporary files is not necessarily allocated at file creation time.
*Action:   Restore access to the device or remove unnecessary files to free
           up space.

Comment: Yeah, your DB is sick, get a DBA to take a look

Answer (score 0):

Check the errors in View->logs> statements.

I had the same issue and found that the user doesn't have permission on temp tablespace.